Migrate spring boot project to Micronaut while using spring annotation
I want to migrate an entire Spring Boot application to a Micronaut application while using Spring Boot annotations. I want the impact of changes to be as minimal as possible, considering that my application relies on Spring Boot Cloud dependencies.
Any ressources or sample project would help.
Thank in advance.

That is obviously not going to work. Micronaut knows nothing about Spring Boot annotations nor about how to work with Spring Cloud.

Have a look at this Micronaut-guide to see what's possible: Run a Spring Boot application as a Micronaut application: https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-spring-boot-maven-java.html
